# How do I create a table for all tables in MySQL

Tags: c++, mysql

I’m using MySQL for C++ and I want to create a new table for all the tables in my second database. The code I have now is:

> CREATE TABLE new_table LIKE original_table;
>
> INSERT INTO new_table SELECT * FROM original_table;

I want to this to work like a loop where all the tables and data in those tables are created for every table and piece of data there is in my second database. Can someone help me?

Comment: @DaleK I corrected it

Answer (score 0):

We can use a stored procedure to do the job in a loop. I just wrote the code and tested it in workbench. Got all my tables(excluding view) from `sakila` database to my `sakila_copy` database:

```
use testdb;
delimiter //
drop procedure if exists copy_tables //
create procedure copy_tables(old_db varchar(20),new_db varchar(20))
begin
declare tb_name varchar(30);
declare fin bool default false;
declare c cursor for select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema=old_db and table_type='BASE TABLE';
declare continue handler for not found set fin=true;

open c;

lp:loop
fetch c into tb_name;

if fin=true then
leave lp;
end if;


set @create_stmt=concat('create table ',new_db,'.',tb_name,' like ',old_db,'.',tb_name,';') ;
prepare ddl from @create_stmt;
execute ddl;
deallocate prepare ddl; 

set @insert_stmt=concat('insert into ',new_db,'.',tb_name,' select * from ',old_db,'.',tb_name,';');
prepare dml from @insert_stmt;
execute dml;
deallocate prepare dml; 

end loop lp;

close c;
end//

delimiter ;

create database sakila_copy;

call testdb.copy_tables('sakila','sakila_copy');

-- after the call, check the tables in sakila_copy to find the new tables
show tables in sakila_copy;
```

Note: As I stated before, only base tables are copied. I deliberately skipped views, as they provide logical access to tables and hold no data themselves.